# Correlation matrix for different treatments in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, pearson

With the code below I have created a correlation matrix. The code below just creates a matrix for all of the data, regardless of treatment. However, a column in my data is treatment. I would like to make two different matrices (one for each treatment type). My treatment a categorical value in column 6 'Treat'. Columns 10 through 44 I would like to create a matrix for.

```
correlations <- cor(Plants[,c(10:44)], use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson")
correlations<-as.matrix(correlations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just two treatment categories then you can make two separate analysis for each level (selecting the data just for particular level). Just replace names `Treatment1` and `Treatment2` with actual names of your treatments.

```
kor1<-cor(Plants[Plants$Treat=="Treatment1",c(10:44)], use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson")
kor2<-cor(Plants[Plants$Treat=="Treatment2",c(10:44)], use="pairwise.complete.obs", method="pearson")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `by` to apply a function to different subsets of your data.

```
by(Plants[10:44], Plants["Treat"],
   cor, use = "pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")
```