# How to customize graph with 2nd correlation line in ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

Following the post, [How to customize lines in ggpairs [GGally]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858337/how-to-customize-lines-in-ggpairs-ggally/36019969#36019969)
I have made graph[image] by using below code;

```
library("GGally")
library("ggplot2")
data(iris)

lowerFn <- function(data, mapping, method = "lm", ...) {
  p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_point(colour = "blue") +
    geom_smooth(method = method, color = "red", ...)
  p
}

ggpairs(
  iris[, 1:4], lower = list(continuous = wrap(lowerFn, method = "lm")),
  diag = list(continuous = wrap("barDiag", colour = "blue")),
  upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 10))
)
```

My question is;

1. How can I made a same style scatter plot matrices graph by adding "Sil" variable effect as correlation lines on graph. Like this graph showing Si variable effect as 2 correlation lines [image]

data is here, (iris data with added Sil variable)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15voAmJ7vcozmHYKYnHxFd_3A3fkkIvzQV6zi44lIEGg/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to colour the points and produce a regression fitted line by
group then you need to map the aesthetics to some variable.

In the general case you can add the mapping to the top level, and
this will split all the panels by group.

```
ggpairs(iris, columns=1:4, mapping=aes(colour=Species))
```

However, I think you need to do a little more work if you only want to plot by group in one section of the panel. One way is to first change your user function to the following, This provides  an additional `emap` parameter that will control the aesthetics in `lowerFn` only.

```
lowerFn <- function(data, mapping, emap=NULL, method = "lm", ...) {
  # mapping <- c(mapping, emap)
  # class(mapping) = "uneval" # need this to combine the two aes
  # Can use this instead
  mapping <- ggplot2:::new_aes( c(mapping, emap))
  p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = method, ...) +
    theme_classic() # to get the white background and prominent axis
  p
}
```

You can then call it with the following, which should leave the diagonal and upper aesthetics alone.

```
ggpairs(
  iris, columns=1:4,
  lower = list(continuous = wrap(lowerFn, 
                                 method = "lm", fullrange=TRUE, se=FALSE,
                                 emap=aes(color=Species))))
```

This produces

[image]

You could of course just hard code your grouping variable into the user function:

```
lowerFn <- function(data, mapping, method = "lm", ...) {
  p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=Species)) +
    geom_smooth(method = method, aes(colour=Species), ...)
  p
}

ggpairs(
  iris, columns=1:4,
  lower = list(continuous = 
                 wrap(lowerFn, method = "lm", 
                      fullrange=TRUE, se=FALSE)))
```

---

Comment: when you add the `colour` parameter to `geom_point`
or `geom_smooth` in your user function it will overrule a mapped `colour` e.g. compare the results from the following

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
  geom_smooth(col="red", se=FALSE)
```

---

**Q? How can I enter key for regression line on the graph?**

If you were using a global / top-level aesthetic you could use `ggpairs(iris, columns=1:4, aes(colour=Species), legend=1)` and normal `ggplot` `theme` functions to control it. This cannot be done here as the grouping variable was used in a custom function. However, the package provides a means to add custom legends with the `legend` argument; you can generate a dummy legend outside of `ggpairs` and then add it in during the plotting.

```
leg <- grab_legend(ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=NA, y=NA, colour=Species)) +
              geom_line() + theme(legend.direction = "horizontal"))

ggpairs(
  iris, columns=1:4, legend=leg,
  lower = list(continuous = 
                 wrap(lowerFn, method = "lm", 
                      emap=aes(color=Species),
                      fullrange=TRUE, se=FALSE))) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: thank you for help, it solved my problem. Further help plz, 1) how can I remove asterisks showing upper layer of graph. 2) how can I enter key for regression line on the graph?

Comment: You're welcome. AFAIK the asterisks are hard-coded but see the `cor_fun` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889222/change-colors-in-ggpairs-now-that-params-is-deprecated/37890371#37890371 for ways to change the relevant function. Re the equation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65360849/how-to-get-r2-with-ggpairs/65363209#65363209 -- you will need to tweak he function to show the eqn. instead of r^2 but you can use the same approach.

Comment: @ user20650, thank you again for help. I will look into the link.

Comment: Hello, I hope you are doing great. is there any way to replace 'corr' in the box with 'R'?

Comment: Hi @washfaq; I wrote a small function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889222/change-colors-in-ggpairs-now-that-params-is-deprecated/37890371#37890371 which resized the corelation text according to the absolute value of the correlation value. Have a lok at that example to see how you can customise it to other statistics or other text.

Comment: ... actually if you are just wanting to change the text from "corr:" to "R:" then `ggally_cor` now takes a `title` argument which looks like it will do this. See the first example in `?ggally_cor`, and change to `p_(ggally_cor(tips, mapping = ggplot2::aes_string(x = "total_bill", y = "tip"), title="R:"))`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works very well. Very much appreciated help.

Comment: Hi User20650, is it possible for you to answer this question, I will be very thankful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459268/is-it-possible-to-split-correlation-box-to-show-correlation-values-for-two-diffe

Comment: @washfaq ; re your new question , if you are wanting separate lines (lower) and correlations (upper) why not just do `ggpairs(iris, columns=1:4, mapping=aes(colour=Species))`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want separate heat map correlation box for both "Si" treatment. is it possible that box can be split into two for treatment effect comparison?

Comment: oh so you want two coloured boxes for each correlation? I'm sure its doable .. likely need to change to using geom_rect (or annotate) instead of the panel.background

Comment: is it possible for you to answer the question for my understanding whenever you got time, I have tried this answer, but couldn't make it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669568/correlation-matrix-for-different-treatments-in-r